# How to turn off SSL verification in GitPitch?

Tags: gitlab-omnibus, gitpitch

I'm trying to make Gitpitch to load presentations from Gitlab-omnibus installed in a local network (that is, not gitlab.com).

What I've done:

1. Pulled Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/knsit/gitpitch/dockerfile
2. Imported Gitpitch sample repository https://github.com/gitpitch/in-60-seconds from Github to our Gitlab
3. `docker run docker run -d --rm --name gitpitch -e GP_GITLAB_BASE=https://gitlab.local.corp/ -e GP_GITLAB_API=https://gitlab.local.corp/api/v4/ -e GP_GITLAB_AS_DEFAULT=true -e GP_GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN=token -e GP_HOST=host -p 9000:9000 knsit/gitpitch`

Please, note s in https. Our Gitlab uses HTTPS, but with self-signed certificate.

I can connect to the port 9000 of the container but browser shows me Error 404, saying that no Pitchme.md file exist in the repository.

I suspect that it is due to self-signed certificate of the Gitlab installation.

Is it possible to turn off checking of certificate validity for GitPitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not maintain the Docker image you are using so I can't speak to it specifically. The official GitPitch image available for deployment on-premises is [GitPitch Enterprise](https://gitpitch.com/enterprise).

That said, if you can customize the configuration for your local instance you might get the behavior you want by activating the following property:

```
play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate=true
```

You can learn more about customizing the configuration for GitPitch Enterprise [here](https://gitpitch.com/docs/enterprise/config/). It might help you to understand a little more about custom configuration for the GitPitch server.

Of course, if you want to unlock the full GitPitch feature set on-premises, get in touch about a GitPitch Enterprise license. Details on the [gitpitch.com](https://gitpitch.com) website.